# How to match incomplete terms in Elasticsearch using Searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using Elasticsearch + Searchkick in my Rails app to index articles. When I search using incomplete words, it does not work. For example:

```
Article.search('feature compatibility').pluck(:name)
# => ["Feature compatibility by mobile device"]

Article.search('feature compatibil').pluck(:name)
# => []
```

My model uses the default Searchkick settings.

Comment: You need to add searchkick text_start: [:attribute_name] in your model

Comment: and then run this on your rails console Article.reindex to add data to the search index.

Comment: @Dnyanarthlonkar tried it, no success.

Comment: @Diego Have you run through this: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#instant-search--autocomplete ?

Comment: @Diego please follow the link pasted by Val, you need to also include typehead.js for autocomplete search.

Comment: I'm not using this for autocomplete. I tried that @Val: `searchkick text_start: [:name, :body]` and then reindexing. Searching for `feature compatibil` still brings no results. Searching for `feature compatibility` does.

Comment: Searching for `feature compatibil` (i.e. part of word) is very similar to autocomplete. You might want to try `match_phrase_prefix` instead, i.e. `Article.search body: {match_phrase_prefix: {name: "feature compatibil"}}`

Comment: @Val, this code gives me `failed to parse search source. unknown search element [match_phrase_prefix]`. Having to change the default behavior sounds wrong to me. If I search for `feature` the article appears, if I type `feature co`, that article is not a match anymore. This sounds very counter intuitive. I can't be the only one having to change this behavior. Or I'm doing something wrong. Raw Elasticsearch queries used to handle these cases, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It doesn't find `co` because `feature compatibility` is indexed to `feature` and `compatibility` by default, i.e. you're not indexing ngrams at all. `match_phrase_prefix` is the only query that will get you what you want without going into ngram-ing your data.

Comment: @Val if that's the case, why does `Article.search('featu')` work?

Comment: You didn't mention that or I missed it somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141977/discussion-between-diego-and-val).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add this to your model (`word_start` not `text_start`)

```
searchkick word_start: [:name, :body]
```

Then you need to delete the index, recreate it and reindex your data.
After that your search queries will work as expected